# Why is $(document).ready needed after the <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why is `$(document).ready` needed after the `<script>` tag?

What would happen if we don't use `$(document).ready`?

Comment: why the downvote?  Question seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @krock The question's English is bad, and it's also rather unclear. I could guess what it means, but why should I? the question should be clarified.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$(document).ready` is javascript code, so it has to be written in `<script>` element and after jQuery is loaded.

If you don't write `$(document).ready`, your code will not wait for *DOM* to load completely and execute the javascript code immediately.

If you're using script in `<head>` that is using/manipulating some elements from DOM, you'll need `ready`, otherwise you'll get `null`/`undefined`.
If you're using script at the end of `<body>`, then you'll be safe as all the elements are loaded.

Quoting as it is from [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.
>
> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.

**Example? Sure!**

**In Head no ready**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    alert($('#myname').val());
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" value="Tushar" id="myname" />
</body>

</html>
```

**At the end of body**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" value="Tushar" id="myname" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    alert($('#myname').val());
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**In head with ready**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert($('#myname').val());
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" value="Tushar" id="myname" />

</body>

</html>
```

For the `<script>` at the end of `<body>`, you can omit `ready`.

Comment: Also see [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), _ready_ in Vanilla JS

Comment: Okay, two downvotes. Downvoter, there must be something that can be improved. Can you add comment here

Answer (score 12):

> Why is `$(document).ready` really need after `<script>` tag when we use javascript.

It isn't.

> What else if we don't use `$(document).ready`

First, understand why people use `ready`: It's used to delay the code within the function you pass into it until jQuery calls that function, which jQuery does when it thinks the document is fully loaded.

JavaScript code within `script` tags runs immediately. If the `script` tag is *above* an element it refers to, the element won't exist when the script runs:

```
<script>
$("#foo").show();
</script>
<div id="foo" style="display: none">...</div>
```

That `div` will not be shown, because it doesn't exist when the code runs. So people use `ready` to delay their code.

There's a better way if you control where your `script` tags go: Just put your `script` tag at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<div id="foo" style="display: none">...</div>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
$("#foo").show();
</script>
</body>
```

All of the elements defined above the `script` tag will exist when the code runs. No need for `ready`.

Answer (score 1):

The ready event occurs when the `DOM` (document object model) has been loaded.

Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a good place to have all other `jQuery` events and functions.

```
//Use ready() to make a function available after the document is loaded:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Like in the example above.
The ready() method specifies what happens when a ready event occurs.

Direct quote from [Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.