# Use of $(document).ready() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

What are the disadvantages of DEFINING (not declaration) all functions in

```
$(document).ready()
```

while developing a large web application of JavaScript/jQuery which also have number of ajax calls for the back end services.

For example:
when i add all my ajax calls in document.ready and those calls going to download large number of data while page is loading what disadvantages i will experience doing so ??

Thanks

Comment: What is the difference of *defining* and *declaring*  for you?

Comment: If you mean you're just assigning values to non-declared variables, the disadvantages are the same as of using any global variables in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558233/why-document-ready-need-after-script-tag/32558249#32558249 This question has the answers why `ready` is used/required

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of the question. Can you show us some example code?

Comment: This questions make NO SENSE at all without you explaining what you think the difference is between defining and declaring?  Since the OP has not clarified what they mean here, this question should be closed as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Document.ready is to make sure that the elements on the pages are completely rendered. So if you have data coming from backend and if you want it to render it to an element in the page, to make sure the element is present on the page you will need to add the call inside document.ready.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are saying the functions are *defined*, but not *declared*, inside the `.ready` call I will assume your code to look something like this:

```
var fn; // declaration
$(document).ready(function () {
  fn = function () { // definition
    // do something
  };
});
```

The main disadvantage is that you cannot call those functions before the DOM tree is ready. If you try to call them earlier you will get an error.

Comment: This isn't really a correct explanation.  Functions defined within a `$(document).ready()` handler can only be called from within that handler whether the DOM tree is ready or not.  They have a limited scope and can only be called from within that scope.

Comment: jfriend00, note that the question explicitly says they are declared outside the .ready function. I will update my answer to better reflect that.

Comment: I don't know what question you are reading.  The word "outside" is never used in this question.

Comment: That is how I read "not declared". If something is not declared at definition time it must have been declared previously.

Comment: That's an assumption on your part.  I did not read it that way.  The question is very unclear and should really just be closed.

Comment: @jfriend00  that's exactly what i have asked for and some more disadvantages which i can give you about my question . for instance it will slows down page speed as if in any case when you are calling all the services by ajax document ready page will kept on loading until all services are called and it will also sends request for the services which you might not be needed at that time

Comment: @TayyabRashid - so why aren't you clarifying your question when multiple people do not understand your question and have asked you to clarify it in comments?  Your question is one close vote away from being closed because of how unclear it is.

Comment: was away and dint know that there is going to be a war on my question :P jokes apart i will edit it