# Best practices for placing the Document Ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes I end up with a lot of code in the `$("document").ready()` function which usually sits inside the `.html` file.

```
 $("document").ready(function() {
    // The DOM is ready!
    // Let the DOM manipulation begin!
 });
```

What are the best practices for locating the `$("document").ready()`. Should it be in a different `.js` file and included in the HTML using:

```
<script src="MyDocReadyJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: _for locating the `$("document").ready()`_?

Comment: Best practice is to not to use it, move the `<script>` at the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: Usually the HTMLs are long and adding a `$('document').ready()` to this with lines of javascript make the overall code very cluttered. Looking for a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Related/Dupe of [`Why $(document).ready need after <script> tag`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558233/why-document-ready-need-after-script-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to put the code before you close `</body>` tag.
In this case you can get rid of "document ready" wrapper because the DOM will be already ready :)