# Trying to toggle text on a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in html

```
<input id="LockUnlock"
       type="submit" 
       class="btn-sm btn-primary" 
       value="@(agent.IsLockedOut ? "Unlock" : "Lock")"/>
```

It correctly sets the value based on the model but I want to toggle the button text when I click it.

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[type = submit]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).text() === "Lock") 
            { 
                $(this).text("Unlock"); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $(this).text("Lock"); 
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Nothing happens when I click the button. I'm not seeing errors in the console window in Chrome.

Comment: Use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).text()`

Comment: Still doesnt work, even if I put an alert("foo"); in the function, it never shows. I think I'm doing something wrong that the method is never called.

Comment: [Difference between val() and text()](//stackoverflow.com/q/807867)

Comment: Where is the `script` included on page? In `<head>`? You might need to wrap the JS code in `ready`.

Comment: remove the `;` from last from else `{ $(this).text("Lock"); };`

Comment: yes, it's in the head. What do you mean, wrap in `ready`?

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function() { $('#LockUnlock').click(function() { ...`

Comment: @Tusher, that made it work! using $(document).ready. Thanks, if you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Stuart [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558249/2025923) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).val()` instead `$(this).text()`.

Also, I fixed some code errors that you had in your question.

```js
 $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "Lock") 
            { 
                $(this).val("Unlock"); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $(this).val("Lock"); 
            }; 
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="LockUnlock"
       type="submit" 
       class="btn-sm btn-primary" 
       value="Unlock"/>
```

> Note: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text) to learn the differences between `.text()` and `.val()`

Comment: Read OP's comments on question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this `<input id="LockUnlock"
       type="submit" 
       class="btn-sm btn-primary" 
       value="@(agent.IsLockedOut ? 'Unlock' : 'Lock')"/>`